# Computer Science — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

**We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!**

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community!

[XKCD 722 http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/computer_problems.png](https://xkcd.com/722/)

We know it's not always easy to get the lights to do the pattern we want 'em to do ;) And as such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

**A MOUSEPAD!**

[image: MOUSEPAD!!!!!!!]

I'll be reaching out to you later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site great!**

Comment: Yay, swag! \o/ Can we order more? ;)

Comment: I am so pumped for this, fam

Comment: Wow, lots of people will be getting swag. I feel like our active regulars -- the heroes of the review queues, and flag/close buttons! -- should get something special.

Comment: Well, this is a great way to get former regulars to revisit the site. (And note that it graduated and got a really nice design.) :)

Comment: Yay, real opportune time to join the forum and earn enough reputation. Got into top 72 just a few days back.

Comment: Where is the link to the form?

Comment: As I explained in the post, @Shreesh, it should be on an e-mail I sent on Friday. Assuming the address listed under your profile is correct (and was so on Friday), you should have received an e-mail from me shortly after this post was posted.

Comment: Got it and thank you JNAT.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Schweet schwag!

Comment: Unfortunately not, @Raphael :\

Comment: I was 1 away...

Comment: Did these ever ship?

Comment: Not yet. They should ship next week, I expect.

Comment: When will the extra tshirts be sent out to others?can I get one? @jnat

Comment: The t-shirt is supposed to be more green than cyan?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks! received the goodies today. This will impress my colleagues!

Comment: Dito! Turns out I ordered one size too large after all, but that leaves me room to "grow". ;D

Comment: Haha! I got a reduced entrance fee for an art museum recently. They said reduction for students and teachers, but I had no proper proof of that with me. Then they decided that a T-shirt with "computer science" was OK. Thanks SE!